# Как правильно написать url определенной новости

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, база-данных, url

Я создаю новостной проект REST API. У меня вопрос, как я могу создать правильный запрос на получение URL в сопоставлении получения, чтобы отображать конкретную статью на сайте. Например, предположим, что у меня есть две статьи с заголовками:

ЯВА ЛУЧШЕ
ЯВА ЛУЧШЕ
Это две разные статьи с одинаковым заголовком, как я могу создать правильный URL-адрес для страницы, чтобы отображать определенные новости. У меня есть идеи, но я думаю, что они не очень хорошие.

@GetMapping ("/ api / news / {article.id name}") -> не правильно, как это улучшить?

У меня возникла идея создать новую сущность в БД, которая будет подсчитывать количество статей, и когда пользователь будет добавлять новые статьи, эта сущность будет принимать его номер. @GetMapping ("/ api / news / {article.counter.number}") -> так "сложно"

Используйте идентификатор в URL-адресе, но я читал, что это плохая идея. @GetMapping ("api / news / {article.id}")

У большинства новостных сайтов есть URL-адреса, подобные этому: ... / news / desperate-search-Survivors-enters-second-day-after-florida-condo-collapse-n1272333

Что это за n1272333? это идентификатор или специальное поле в БД артиклей сущностей или просто номер статьи в БД?

Comment: Скорее всего это заглушка для номера в стринговом формате, чтобы сцепить ее с другими строками.

Comment: Обычно в таких url все завязано на это вот `12723337`, а остальной текст можно заменить на произвольный набор букв.